# How to organize http-requests with responses in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a greasemonkey-script with the function `GM_xmlhttpRequest` it's similair to `xmlhttpRequest` but allows cross-site-scripting etc.

I am making a bunch of paralel http-requsts to various pages and then use onload to read some data from those pages. Based on the result, I make new http-requst. Here is an example, the code might not work, it's more to illustrate the stuff i'm working with.

```
function calleniro(nicerows, attempt){
    if( attempt === 1){
        var who = nicerows.contact.firstname+' '+nicerows.contact.lastname;
        var where = ''
    }else if(attempt === 2){
        var who = nicerows.contact.firstname+' '+nicerows.contact.lastname;
        var where = nicerows.contact.postal;
    }else if(attempt === 3){
        var who = nicerows.contact.firstname+' '+nicerows.contact.lastname;
        var where = nicerows.contact.adress;
    }

    var url = 'http://personer.eniro.se/resultat/'+who+'/'+where;
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    onload: function(data) {
        data = $.parseHTML(data.response);
        var phone = $(data).find('.tel.row a').map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        //one company, save the data
        if(vCard.length = 1){
            //adding the company if we find a phonenumber or more.
            if (phone.length > 0){ 
                nicerows.contact.phone = phone;
            }
        more than one company.
        }else if(vCard > 1){
            attempt++;
            calleniro(nicerows, attempt)
        }


    }
})
}
```

This very fast turns in to a bubushka doll-hydra with ever branching onload functions. It's very hard to track what's going on. I would like to separate the functions more to something like this for example:

```
var contact = callenrio(foo,bar)
//the next thing should happen after onload only.
if(contact.tel){ 
save(contact);
}
else{
callenrio(foobar,barfoo)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is more or less captured within the basics of [Object-Oriented Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_Constructor). In it's most basic form you could do:

```
function calleniro(foo,bar)
{
    this.tel = foo+"-"+bar;
}
contact = new calleniro("555","7777");
if (contact.tel)
...
```

But since you're performing an ajax query, you run into some scoping problems, since `this` has a different meaning when you're inside `GM_xmlhttpRequest`. But you can fix this with a closure. The following is a $.ajax example that passes `this` into the $.ajax function as `obj`, so instead of using `this.tel`, we're using `obj.tel` and avoid the scope problem..

```
(function(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            obj.tel = data;
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Let me know if this makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: This is great! I haven't really used object-oriented javascript before.*reading up on it now* How would you structure the classes etc. My current idea is to make a class for each type of http-request. And create a new object for every single http-request. Another problem is that $.ajax won't work cross-site.